# Ubuntu 14.04 loosing wifi connection

Tags: wireless, networking

I using Ubuntu 14.04 and i connecting to wifi using network manager from system tray.
The wifi works fine, but after 5 minutes i loosing internet , but I'm still connected to wifi and i need reconnect with network to have internet again. I sending log from wireless_script. I hope somebody will help me with this problem. Thanks a lot!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux kris-ubuntu 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1532:0016 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Mouse
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

rtl8192cu              67723  0 
rtl_usb                18448  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53172  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              626557  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TNCAP2355AD-TescoBroadband"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:21   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [TNCAP2355AD-TescoBroadband] ----------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           65 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    BL-MP01-DFAADC:  Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100
    *TNCAP2355AD-TescoBroadband: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.101
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TNCAP2355AD-TescoBroadband"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003585d7ba52
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001A544E4341503233353541442D546573636F42726F616462616E64
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A1E181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD9B0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001092DD212FAE0F5466B45D5AB5C22E90F31021000B546563686E69636F6C6F721023000E546563686E69636F6C6F72205447102400043538326E10420010623736663736343562336131623566391054000800060050F204000110110012546563686E69636F6C6F722054473538326E100800020004103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180206000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-10 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"BL-MP01-DFAADC"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000b1d41fa49
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E424C2D4D5030312D444641414443
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E1117FF000000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B070000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101030003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0500001D127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     A4F9BAD0CEC9B9B92666E34
alias:          usb:v7392p7822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p624Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3309d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0061d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8186d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17ABd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846pF001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9021d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8178d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0056d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp2103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp2102d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019p1201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFBd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFFAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF9d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pAFF7d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp317Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v9846p9041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v4855p0091d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v4855p0090d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3359d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3358d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p648Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pED17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB2Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019p4902d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3308d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3357d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v103Cp1629d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v4856p0091d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0EB0p9071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0077d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p005Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp5088d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8189d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8188d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v06F8pE033d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp11F2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1102d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8178d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8754d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp819Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp818Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp817Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8177d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8176d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8170d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp018Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8191d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:CE:B2:C5:67:D2:52:22:6B:47:71:2C:FD:8A:F6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     5F97DAF0B5791785FB2AA02
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:CE:B2:C5:67:D2:52:22:6B:47:71:2C:FD:8A:F6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     27E91755814596D634B7709
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:CE:B2:C5:67:D2:52:22:6B:47:71:2C:FD:8A:F6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     32F826C623BC49F764F7974
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:CE:B2:C5:67:D2:52:22:6B:47:71:2C:FD:8A:F6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist r8192se_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan3"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan4"

##### dmesg #####

[   24.589019] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   24.669363] rtl8192cu: MAC address: <MAC address removed>
[   24.669370] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   24.669629] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   24.669672] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   24.671316] Error: Driver 'rtl8192cu' is already registered, aborting...
[   24.688251] Error: Driver 'rtl8192cu' is already registered, aborting...
[   25.086302] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   25.086904] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   29.508804] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   29.541401] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   29.905140] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   29.905474] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   31.146029] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   31.159549] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   31.162235] wlan0: authenticated
[   31.163717] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   31.190499] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   31.190563] wlan0: associated
[   31.190577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  529.724439] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  530.529830] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  530.543886] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  530.556268] wlan0: authenticated
[  530.556786] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  530.562624] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  530.562682] wlan0: associated
[  872.035718] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  872.815570] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  872.828640] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  872.850009] wlan0: authenticated
[  872.851193] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  872.874119] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  872.874159] wlan0: associated
[ 2990.208348] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 2990.989410] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 2991.001577] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2991.013158] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2991.016646] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 2991.096376] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 2991.096412] wlan0: associated
[ 3315.946936] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 3316.757009] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 3316.769436] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 3316.771528] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3316.772367] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 3316.794330] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 3316.794374] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

install common wifi drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but it didn't help :(i still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Potentially an energy control problem. Try turning off energy control on your interface:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Change `wlan0` to your actual interface name.

**NB:** You'll have to do it every time you connect to your network.

Comment: I try power off it , but i've got:                              Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.