# Losing wifi on restart [BCM4360 - 18.04 LTS]

Tags: wireless, 18.04, broadcom, macbook, restart

I have a macbook air (2015, Model A1465). The chipset is BCM4360:

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: 98:e0:d9:7e:d9:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:c1200000-c1207fff memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

I use rEFInd to boot into Ubuntu 18.04, no problems during install execpt for no wifi. I hotspoted and installed the broadcom-sta-dkms drivers. Everyhthing goes smoothly, and when I restart wifi works.

When I restart the machine, I lose wifi.

I downloaded the broadcom package: `broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-8_all.deb` and ran:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall broadcom-sta-dkms
```

getting the following output:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall broadcom-sta-dkms                                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,204 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 211030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-8_all.deb ...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  broadcom-sta
Version: 6.30.223.271
Kernel:  4.15.1-041501-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.1-041501-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs........

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-8) over (6.30.223.271-8) ...
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-8) ...
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.1-041501-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.1-041501-generic
This system does't support Secure Boot
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.1-041501-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs.......

DKMS: install completed.
```

rEFInd tries to boot into the `.old-dkms` image by default. So I enter into single user mode and boot from the new `initrd.img-4.15.1-041501-generic`.

The wifi works again, until I reboot. And so the cycle repeats!!

I've tried many things, including blacklisting every other driver/package that could be interfering, but nothing works. Here's list I have so far `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
blacklist b43-fwcutter
blacklist bcm43
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

Executing:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

makes no difference

Similar questions have been asked previously, but don't really address my particular issue

- [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)
- [How to manually install Broadcom BCM4360 driver on Ubuntu on MacBook Air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803184/how-to-manually-install-broadcom-bcm4360-driver-on-ubuntu-on-macbook-air)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 loosing wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493104/ubuntu-14-04-loosing-wifi-connection)

TL;DR: I lose wifi every time I restart. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

This is the source: [BCM4360 802.11ac not working w/ 4.15.0-29-lowlatency recent update](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397051).